# Vue JS watcher performance tradeoff

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle, watch

I went into some dispute about watcher trade-offs and it's not clear for me how much impact it causes for you to watch the changes on some javascript object.
So the question is the following:
What has a less performance impact and why? And the two options to choose from:

1. Recreating the component each time you need that (which invokes recreating the internals, initializing getters/setters fields, initializing component's watcher, registering to observe changes and initializing component's MessageChannel)
2. Or by keeping watcher registered and never destroy/recreate the component

The watcher isn't watching any weird array of thousands or hundreds of items, as I said, it's an small object with four fields, no nested things. The thing which I can't understand, is it a better thing to constantly run an watcher instead of recreating the component just to avoid it constantly running ?
Hope there will be someone with an argument
Thank you!

Comment: Vuejs watchers detect changes via getters/setters instead of polling your data constantly. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked

Comment: @MarcusVilete so from what I have read, it means there is no impact at all by using watchers, is it ? What is the downside of using them then?

Comment: Performance wise, i don't see any downside... I'm no Vue 'guru' but i believe thats how it Works.